# jQuery prepend optgroup with label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prepend an optgroup to a select element

HTML:

`<select id="select"></select>`

JS :

```
var newItemMessage = "For new item start typing";
$("#select").prepend('<optgroup label='+newItemMessage+'></optgroup>');
```

here is my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nx19jotb/1/

the problem is, that only the first word from the variable is added to the label,
this is appended (note the quotes after the first word)

`<optgroup label="For" new item start typing></optgroup>`

What am I missing?

Comment: missing double quotes.... It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the original code:

```
var newItemMessage = "For new item start typing";
$("#select").prepend('<optgroup label='+newItemMessage+'></optgroup>');
```

the fix:

```
var newItemMessage = "For new item start typing";
$("#select").prepend('<optgroup label="'+newItemMessage+'"></optgroup>');
```

Comment: thank you, I am banging my head against the desk now :D

Answer (score 1):

this one works as well

```
var newItemMessage = "For new item start typing";
$("<optgroup>").attr('label', newItemMessage).prependTo("#select");
```